# Sum of integer values of a Future

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

I'm trying to parse a HTML document, get all the image-sources and then add the size of all pictures together.
Parsing the document works fine, so does getting the image-sources and getting their size.

```
main(){
  print("Please input an URL");
  var url = stdin.readLineSync();

  getImageUrls(url).then((list) {
    list.forEach((imageUrl) {
      getImageSize(imageUrl).then((r) {
        print("$imageUrl, Size: $r bytes");
      });
    });
  });
}

Future<int> getImageSize(String url){
  final completer = new Completer();
  new StreamController()..stream.listen((str) => completer.complete(imageSize(str)))..add(url);
  return completer.future;
}

imageSize(String url){
  return http.get(url).then((response) => response.bodyBytes.length);
}
```

I'm struggeling to add the size of each individual image together into one integer.
I figured I could do something like this

```
main(){
  int total = 0;
  print("Please input an URL");
  var url = stdin.readLineSync();

  getImageUrls(url).then((list) {
    list.forEach((imageUrl) {
      getImageSize(imageUrl).then((r) {
        print("$imageUrl, Size: $r bytes");
        total += r;
      });
    });
  });
  print(total);
}
```

but then I'd need wait for getImageUrls to finish before Im able to print my total.

Can anyone push me in the right direction? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: I believe what you need here is Future.wait https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Future#id_wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the "new" `async`/`await`

```
main() async {
  int total = 0;
  print("Please input an URL");
  var url = stdin.readLineSync();

  var list = await getImageUrls('url');
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var imageUrl = list[i];
    var r = await getImageSize(imageUrl);
    print("$imageUrl, Size: $r bytes");
    total += r;
  }
  print(total);
}
```

or the `Future.wait` as mentioned in a comment

```
main(){
  int total = 0;
  print("Please input an URL");
  var url = stdin.readLineSync();

  getImageUrls(url).then((list) {
    return Future.wait(list.map((r) {
      return getImageSize(imageUrl).then((r) {
        print("$imageUrl, Size: $r bytes");
        total += r;
      });
    });
  }).then((_) => print(total));
}
```

Comment: Neither code fragment works for me. The first one with async/await looks good on paper, but since we're not waiting on total to be filled up, it just prints it out immideatly, which is 0 at that point.

The second one I don't totall understand. We're waiting on a future to complete, but where did the map come from? And how are you going to use the variable imageUrl, when its not defined anywhere in that snippet?

Comment: I fixed the first one. `forEach` doesn't work with `await` because there is no way to return the future (sorry, forgot that). `list.map(...)` calls `(r) {...}` for each element in `list` (maps the input to the output using the passed function) and produces an iterable with the results (the futures returned from `getImageSize()`). `Future.wait()` waits for all futures returned from `list.map(...)`. The `print(total)` needs to be connected with `.then()` so it is executed when the previous future is completed.